# How to print all protobuf fields in gRPC response, even when empty

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I'm writing a gRPC service with a protobuf definition as follows:

```
message MyRequest {
}

message MyResponse {
  string username = 1;
  repeated string schools = 3;
}

service MyService {
  rpc Service(MyRequest) returns (MyResponse) {}
}
```

The service returns a list of schools for the current user. Sometimes there will be no schools for a user, and I want the response in the `schools` field to be an empty list, but instead the field is just missing from the response.

What do I need to do to get the `schools` field to always be present in the response, even when it's an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

In Protocol Buffers repeated fields are simply a field that has multiple values sent on-the-wire. With that encoding there is no difference between "empty" and "not present."

If you need to distinguish between empty and "not present" you need to wrap the repeated field in its own message and check whether that message is present.

```proto
message MyRequest {
}

message MyResponse {
  string username = 1;
  Schools schools = 2;
}

message Schools {
  repeated string names = 1;
}

service MyService {
  rpc Service(MyRequest) returns (MyResponse) {}
}
```

`myResponse.hasSchools() == false` means "not present".